# Wrong conversion of NSTimeInterval to hours and minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm building an app whereas a part of the logic is to sum up a lot of NSTimeIntervals and convert the result to hours and minutes.

I'm using a for-loop to add the intervals like so

```
NSTimeInterval totalInterval = 0;
for (MyObject *currentObject in _myList)
{
    totalInterval += [currentObject.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentObject.startDate];
}
```

This function will return an object of type NSDateComponents:

```
// Get conversion to months, days, hours, minutes
unsigned int unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth;

NSDate *startDate = [self dateByOmittingSeconds:[NSDate date]]; // get the current time
NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:totalInterval sinceDate:startDate];

return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate  toDate:endDate  options:0];
```

Which I then format to a more legible type (NSString) for the user to read:

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(NSDateComponents *)workhours
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldh %ldm", (long)[workhours hour], (long)[workhours minute]];
}
```

But the result from the `timeFormatted` function outputs 14h 11m, while the seconds in totalInterval is correct (137460s).

**Any idea why this happens?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use `NSDate` or `NSDateComponents` for this.

`NSTimeInterval` is a number of seconds. Simple math gives you hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
NSInteger hours = totalInterval / 3600;
NSInteger minutes = totalInterval / 60 % 60;
NSInteger seconds = totalInterval % 60;
```

Comment: Tried doing math before like that, but faced problems whereas it could display 8:58 instead of 8:59, etc. Do you think this is the best solution? Keeping in mind the possible inaccuracy of arithmetic without NSNumbers?

Comment: `totalInterval` is a `double` with fractional seconds. Perhaps you could round `totalInterval` before getting the hours, minutes, and seconds. If you don't want seconds then adjust to round to the nearest minute as needed.

Comment: I've made adjustments so that every NSDate stored in my app will only include hours and minutes, no seconds or nanoseconds. It has to be a 100% accurate interval in hours and minutes, with absolutely no mistakes.

Comment: The question was about converting `totalInterval` to hours and minutes. Are you saying the `totalInterval` isn't correct? That's a whole different question/issue.

Comment: totalInterval is correct, but I have to make sure that the displayed result in hours and minutes is exactly correct, without a chance for miscalculations. If you can confirm that that is indeed the case, then simple arithmetic will do the trick for me

Comment: Did you try my code? Are you not getting the expected value? If not, what values are you getting for a given totalInterval?

Comment: I haven't tried now, but I have experienced before that doing / 3600 and similar could result in miscalculations. I wanted to know if you had experienced anything like that, or if you're sure that this code will deliver the expected result, given that the NSDates doesn't contain seconds

Comment: For a given `totalInterval` my code will give you the proper number of hours, minutes, and seconds. I can't speak at all to what you are doing to get `totalInterval`.

Comment: I understand. Basically I have a list of objects, each containing both a start date and an end date with no seconds. I'm doing a for-loop through all the objects and summarizing all the intervals between said dates in all of the objects to totalInterval

Comment: You need to verify whether `totalInterval` is correct or not. Again, that's a completely different question. Once that is correct, my answer to this question will work.

Comment: "I've made adjustments so that every NSDate stored in my app will only include hours and minutes, no seconds or nanoseconds" sounds like it may be a misuse of `NSDate`, @Erik, although it's hard to tell. You might consider whether you'd be better served by only storing `NSDateComponents` or only `NSTimeInterval`s in the first place.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I see your point. Problem is that I need to know the dates as well - the start and end date.

Comment: @rmaddy considering my original code, any clue on why that wouldn't work? It may not be optimal, but it would be clever to learn why it didn't work

Comment: Probably because you needlessly specified the `NSCalendarUnitDay` and `NSCalendarUnitMonth` units.

Comment: Indeed it was. Could you please explain why? What if the time span stretched across multiple days?

Comment: Read the docs for `NSCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:`.

Comment: "There is no need to specify any more components than those in which you are interested". So I only have to specify the value I want. But why would it "hurt" to specify more? - say I wanted to know the month for instance

Comment: These comments have gone on far too long already. This isn't a discussion forum. I'd suggest you close out this question since it has been answered. If you have a new question about the specific your date handling or how `NSCalendar` works, post a new question specific to that issue. Myself and others will be happy to help you in any other questions you might post.